# _v.context.$implicit.handler is not a function

Tags: angular, angular-compiler

I'm working on a grid component which has actions array that will presented as buttons

```
<td *ngFor="let action of actions">
        <button type='button' (click)='action.handler()'>{{action.title}}</button>
</td>
```

when I try this I got the following error

```
_v.context.$implicit.handler is not a function
```

Answer (score 1):

Oooh, I got it

I shouldn't pass the handler as a string, i should pass the function reference itself

so the caller should be like this

```
this.actions = [{title: 'Edit', handler: this.editItem}];
```

instead of

```
this.actions = [{title: 'Edit', handler: 'editItem'}];
```